# @property with @staticmethod in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I am trying to use both `@staticmethod` and `@property` on a function `bar()` so that the result is returned by `Foo.bar` and not `Foo.bar()`.

However, `Foo.bar` is returning `<property object at 0x107e9cb30>` instead of the expected string `bar`.

Why is the `@property` decorator not working?

```py
def do_work(str):
    return str

class Foo: 
    @property
    def foo(self):
        return do_work('foo')

    @staticmethod
    @property
    def bar():
        return do_work('bar')

f = Foo()
print(f.foo)      # foo
print(Foo.bar)    # <property object at 0x107e9cb30>
```

*Using Python 3.7.4*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7864317/2482744

Comment: @AlexHall Is the solution to my question something known as *class property*?