# Python metaclass - make class property accessible via class and class instance

Tags: python, pycharm, metaclass, type-hinting

Using python 3.7, I have created a class property in a metaclass. I would like to be able to access the property via the class itself or an instantiated object of the class. I can emulate it by creating a class property AND an instance property, but it screws with PyCharm's type hinting. Here's what I consider the ideal set up:

```
class Meta(type):
    @property
    def cls_prop(cls) -> str:
        return 'foo'


class A(metaclass=Meta):
    pass
```

But unfortunately, here are the results:

```
>>> A.cls_prop
'foo'
>>> a = A()
>>> a.cls_prop
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'cls_prop'
```

Adding an instance property to `A` that calls to the class property works at runtime, but PyCharm's type introspection gets confused (it starts treating `A.cls_prop` as a `property` instead of a `str`):

```
class A(metaclass=Meta):
  @property
  def cls_prop(self) -> str:
      return self.__class__.cls_prop

>>> A.cls_prop
'foo'
>>> a = A()
>>> a.cls_prop
'foo'
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: IIRC you can register the attribute in the dictionary passed to `Meta.__new__()`.

Comment: Properties are *class* attributes, not quasi-instance methods. `A.cls_prop` is just special syntax for accessing `Meta.cls_prop` and passing `A` to its getter/setter as appropriate. There is no connection between `cls_prop` and an instance of `A`.

Comment: To paraphrase the usual quote, 99% of people don't need to know what a metaclass is (and this was *before* `__init_subclass__` was introduced to handle many of the use cases previously handled by metaclasses).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [@staticmethod with @property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697501/staticmethod-with-property)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do is better accomplished using a parent class:

```
class Parent:
    @property
    def cls_prop(self):
        return 'foo'

class A(Parent):
    pass

>>> a = A()
>>> a.cls_prop
'foo'
>>>> A.cls_prop
<property object at 0x7f1afcb190e8>
```

If you also want to be able to access `A.cls_prop` directly on the class (i.e. without creating an instance), you might want to look at this other question: [@staticmethod with @property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697501/staticmethod-with-property)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is that `property`, howver a handy thing in Python, is not designed to fullfill all possible use cases.

It is a nice use of the descriptor protocol, and is meant for instance properties, and just remains accessible as itself when called from the class.

Having an anologue to `property` that would work both from the class and from the instance is just a matter of writting a class with a proper `__get__` method - 
for a fixed string, it could be as simples as:

```py
class MyProperty:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
         return self.value 

class MyClass:
   cls_prop = MyProperty("foo")
```

(the big difference to property is returning the value
even is "instance" is None)

And, if you want, you can re-implement property 's niceties,
such as be able to work as a decorator, and have decorators
for the `setter` and `deleter` as well.