# Overriding parents namespace variable

Tags: python, namespaces, metaclass

I am trying to understand Python classes before I delve into metaclasses. I have come upon some code I can't figure out. In this situation, classes are not using **self** but rather class namespaces (no option for using self, hence the question here). How can I define in one class some namespace variables, and then override a value they all depend on, in the child classes?

**First Case**

```
class B():
    potato = "hey"
    test = potato
    #here would go a lot of more code that just depends on that potato value

class c(B):
    B.potato = "not hey"

c_potato = c().test
print(c_potato)
```

It prints **hey**. That I understand because **test** is pointing to the string "hey", which is not mutable. Changing `B.potato = "not hey"` only changes class namespace **potato** to a new string, but it doesn't change what **test** is pointing to. So I thought, hey what if I do it with a list, that's by reference right?

```
class B():
    potato = ["hey"]
    test = potato[0]

class c(B):
    B.potato[0] = "not hey"

c_potato = c().test
print(c_potato)
```

In my mind, this should have worked. I have not changed what **potato** is pointing to, but rather the value. No? But I understand that it **wont'** actually work because **test** is pointing to **potato[0]** instead of just **potato**. So yea, I get why this also prints **hey**.

I realised then, if **test** needs to point to the result, which is not mutable, then what I"m trying to do with namespaces is impossible.

```
class B():

    @staticmethod
    def get_potato():
      return "hey"

    potato = get_potato.__func__
    test = potato()

class c(B):

    @staticmethod
    def get_potato():
      return "not hey"

    B.potato = "6"

c_potato = c().test
print(c_potato)
```

I have changed here the **entire** value of **B.potato** but by now **test** already points to the result of the parent's **potato()**, so it doesn't matter and still prints out **"hey"**.

So then I thought, could **metaclasses** fix this? Apparently yeah, it can.

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        x = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        x.potato = "basic hey"
        if 'meta_args' in attrs:
            x.potato = attrs['meta_args'][0]
            del attrs['meta_args'] # clean up
        x.test = x.potato    
        return x

class A():
  pass

class B(A, metaclass=Meta):
  meta_args = ["super hey"]
  pass

class C(B):
    meta_args = ["not hey"]

b = B().test
c = C().test
print(b)
print(c)
```

And that correctly prints **super hey** fo **b** and **not hey** for **c**. Question is, could this be done without metaclasses? My brain hurts at this point.

Comment: `B.potato = "not hey"` inside a `class` doesn't make much sense to begin with.

Comment: Your basic misunderstanding seems to be that nothing is ***pointing*** to anything here. `test` *is* the value `"hey"`. You're assinging `"hey"` to `test` in various ways, and that's that. You're then never assigning anything else to it, so it stays that way. If you want the `.test` attribute to resolve dynamically based on something else, you probably want to make it a `@property`?!

Comment: You are mostly fighting your mind around variable assignment there, and doing very little in what classes or metaclasses should do.  Just don't  go there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have seem, you made a lot of experimentation with "surprising" results, with simple things, like assigning the first element of a list to a variable, to release you had wrong concepts about the issue.

Why do you think you have "nailed" it and got it right when you go past simple, and "find out" you can "change a value" with a metaclass?

No - just going on with your earlier trends you still have wrong assumptions.

The code in the metaclass `__new__` method, just as the code in a class *body* is run once when each class is created. Variables are created, assigned, and not changed after that.

Your "metaclass experiment" cfeates a new value for both `potato` and `test` attributes by setting then on the *new* class at the time this new class (C) is created.

There is nothing "meta" in that that would be different from doing:

```
class B:
    potato = 0

class C(B):
   pass

C.potato = 1

print(C.potato)   # Hey it works!
```

If you want "magic changing values", behaving like calculated values do on spreadsheet programs,  Python has a mechanism to do that, and it is not related to metaclasses: these are the "descriptors". Of which the mostwell known are the created with the built-in `property`.

So, descriptors do what you are trying with your exploring: they look like an ordinary attribute uon reading or writting, but can trigger and be calculated by any amount of code "behind the scenes". They are truly a mechanism that can be used to implement several aspects of "reactive programing".

But as they are meant to be used, not toyed with, the most popular form, `property` is designed to work on class instances  - not a silly using of classes as just namespaces.

So, I'd advise you to switch to that, and you will have a lot more of exploring to do:

```py
class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.potato = Hey

    @property
    def test(self):
        return self.potato

c = B()
print(c.test)
c.potato = "not hey"
print(c.test)
```

Comment: as I said, and @deceze put it as well, for practical purposes this kind of thing is done with instances.
If I get sometime later I may augment the answer for that.

Comment: Thank you for the code + explanation. I would definitely be using property had I not being told I can't use "self". That's why I set it as part of the limit on the question. Thank you!

Comment: Don't worry about augmenting it, I'll delete the question since it seems the problem was too "out there" by not using self. I found it interesting to try and solve it as such. Thank you though :)

Comment: "properties" are an specific type of descriptors as I said. I recall writting down the recipe for "class level properties"  - I will check  for the link.

Comment: I will wait for that link before deleting this whole thing then :) Thank you!

Comment: There is this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59894757/python-metaclass-make-class-property-accessible-via-class-and-class-instance/59899879#59899879

it is ratehr straightforward. And I advise you to read about the descriptor protocol here:
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors  - actually, if you read all that document (datamodel), it should give you some nice insights into the language.

Comment: Seems I can't delete the question, so I'll mark your answer. Thank you for your explanation and time!

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a `@property`:

```
class B:
    potato = 'hey'

    @property
    def test(self):
        return self.potato


class C(B):
    potato = 'not hey'
```

What you did is assign `"hey"` to `test` in one way or another. Its value won't change unless you actually assign something else to `test`. By making it a `@property`, the function `def test` is invoked every time you access `.test`, so its value can be computed dynamically; in this case based on the value of `potato`. The subclass declares its own `potato`, which shadows the parent's `potato` property.

Comment: It's entirely unclear why that restriction on `self` exists or how else it would be possible to work around it. You'll have to provide a more real example than your toy code.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation + code. I would go for property had I not been told not to use "self". It's a problem I was given and it's the solution I came up with. I can't provide a "real" world example because it was a made up problem to begin with.