# How to fix assignment static typing errors between class property and inherited overrides of non-property members?

Tags: python, properties, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

Lets say I'm using this implementation of classproperty
[@staticmethod with @property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697501/staticmethod-with-property/7864317#7864317) :

```
class classproperty(property):
    def __get__(self, cls, owner):
        return classmethod(self.fget).__get__(None, owner)()
```

- this is useful for instance-less classes *(like Java Interfaces)* when you still want to use the property decorator but you don't have a `self` , just a `cls`

How could you satisfy linters and cast the classmethods such that
when overrides occur of them, you won't get linter errors that type Callable[[Type], IntendedType] is not IntendedType ?

Here is an example:

```
Class A:
   @classproperty
   def foo(cls) -> str:
      return 'bar'

class B(A):
   foo = 'not bar'
```

when I run ***mypy*** on this code, I get the following error:

```
error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "str", base class "A" defined the type as "Callable[[A], str]")  [assignment]
```

It looks like the way to deal with this would be to:

```
Class A:
   @classproperty
   def foo(cls) -> str:
      return 'bar'
   foo = cast(str, foo)
```

But that just feels wrong (Also it doesn't work).

Is there some way to achieve the same result by modifying some parts of `classproperty` ?

other than adding some comment at the beginning of the file to entirely ignore linters checks? (which I am not interested at, not at the beginning of the file nor per specific lines either)

Comment: Can't you override `foo` in B using another `@classproperty` method?

Comment: Overriding an inherited property to make it *not* a property seems like a terrible idea, design-wise.

Comment: What's the point of the property in the first place, just to make `A.foo` read-only?